# $(document).height() and html height:100% issue

Tags: jquery

So I've got this function that fires when the the scroll is 500px above the bottom of the page, in theory.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';
    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is, my html NEEDS to be height:100% so the document height and window height will be the 'same', right?
So the function doesn't work, except in chrome/safari on OS X where you get a little bounce at the bottom and the window.scrolltop is momentarily more than the document height.

How can I make this function work with my html being 100% height?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';
    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('body').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';
    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('body').height() - intBottomMargin) {

          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Doesn't work either, nothing happens at all.

How can I make this function work with my html and body being 100% height?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('body').height()` instead of `$(document).height()`.

Comment: According to the Chrome DevTools or FireBug, what is the height of each?

Comment: body and html are both 1675px high.

Comment: I forgot to mention, body is also 100% height(It's this way so I can have a sidebar with content inside it that scrolls up/down without moving the main content area).

Comment: The body height should cover all content, and overflows the window height. If I resize my browser window to be 300px high, the body can still be 1000+.

Comment: Sorry, I was giving you the width (been a long day), height is 990px for body and html, because both are set to 100% height, both are same height when window is resized.

Comment: Do you have a div inside that surrounds all your content?

Comment: html > body > .main-content > .center > .post

Comment: Can you use `$(".main-content").height()`?

Comment: if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) { has the same effect as body/document, none of them work for some reason.

Comment: if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) { works only IF I remove height:100% from the html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27361/discussion-between-andy-and-mooseman)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scrollTop() >= $('body').height() - intBottomMargin
```

Should do the trick. $(window).height() wont return the same height in firefox as in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, and came upon a possible solution. You could clone and load body's contents off-screen, calculate the height, and then remove said clone.

```
function getDocumentHeight() {
    var $temp = $("<div>")
        .css("position","absolute")
        .css("left","-10000px")
        .append($("body").html());

    $("body").append($temp);
    var h = $temp.height();
    $temp.remove();
    return h;
}
```

[Source](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/finding-real-body-height-using-jquery/)